# Converting JSON format string into a real object in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, web-services, slim

I have an JSON format string which I want to add like a parameter to atach to a post request.

I'm trying to do the reques, when I do the request I get this error from my web service:

```
#0 /opt/assets/WS/ws.php(48): Slim\Slim::handleErrors(8, 'Trying to get p...', '/opt/assets/WS/...', 48, Array)
#1 [internal function]: {closure}()
#2 /opt/assets/WS/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(468): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#3 /opt/assets/WS/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php(1357): Slim\Route->dispatch()
#4 /opt/assets/WS/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/Flash.php(85): Slim\Slim->call()
#5 /opt/assets/WS/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/MethodOverride.php(92): Slim\Middleware\Flash->call()
#6 /opt/assets/WS/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/PrettyExceptions.php(67): Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride->call()
#7 /opt/assets/WS/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php(1302): Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions->call()
#8 /opt/assets/WS/ws.php(59): Slim\Slim->run()
#9 {main}
```

It's like the request doesn't contains a real JSON object. How can I transform it? I did some tricks but seems doesn't work.
That's my script:

```
assets.controller('AfegirTipusActiusCtrl', function ($scope, $http){

                    // Camps formulari text pla
                 /*   $scope.nomAtribut = "<input type='text' name='firstname'>";
                    $scope.mida = "<input type='number' name='firstname'>";
                    $scope.obligatori = "<input type='checkbox' name='vehicle' value='yes'>";   */

                    // Construeix combo
                    $http.get('http://10.0.203.73/WS/ws.php/getCombo/1').success(function(data) {
                        $scope.options = data;
                    });

                    $scope.atributs = [];

                    $scope.addRow = function(){
                        var newRow = {
                            nomAtribut: "",
                            tipus: "",
                            mida: "",
                            prioritat: "",
                            obligatori: "",
                            observacions: ""
                        }
                        $scope.atributs.push(newRow);
                    }

                   /* $scope.addField = function() {
                        $scope.atributs.push(newRow);
                    };*/

                    $scope.prioritat = $scope.atributs.length;

                    // Envia atributs a WS
                    $scope.sendRow = function(){
                        var d = "{'nomAtribut': 'marca','tipus': 'String','mida': '15','prioritat': '1','obligatori': 'No'}";
                        $http.post("http://10.0.203.73/WS/ws.php/tipusactius/alta", angular.toJson(d)).success(function(data){
                            $scope.status = data;
                        })
                    }
            });
```

Edit:

Also I add the php Slim function which parse the request:

```
 $app->post('/tipusactius/alta', function () use ($app) {
        $json = $app->request->getBody();
        header("Content-Type: application/json");
        $json_decode = json_decode($json); // $json_decode conte l'bjecte format a partir del json del request
        echo $json_decode->{'tipus'};

     //   $sql = "INSERt INTO atributs_actiu (nomAtribut, midaAtribut, tipus_actius_idtipus_actius, atributObligatori, ordre, tipusAtributs_idTipus, observacions
     //                  , combo_idcombo, combo_codi) values ('".$json_decode->{'nomAtribut'}."', '".$json_decode->{'mida'}."', 1, '0', 1, 1, 'atribut de prova', 1, 1)";
        $sql = "INSERt INTO atributs_actiu (nomAtribut, midaAtribut, tipus_actius_idtipus_actius, atributObligatori, ordre, tipusAtributs_idTipus, observacions
                       , combo_idcombo, combo_codi) values ('".$json_decode->{'nomAtribut'}."', '3', 1, '0', 1, 1, 'atribut de prova', 1, 1)";

        $mysqli=getDB();
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
 });
```

Solved:
Like @vidriduch told:

```
$scope.sendRow = function() {
    var d = {
        'nomAtribut': 'marca',
        'tipus': 'String',
        'mida': '15',
        'prioritat': '1',
        'obligatori': 'No'
    };

    $http.post("http://10.0.203.73/WS/ws.php/tipusactius/alta", angular.toJson(d)).success(function(data) {
        $scope.status = data;
})};
```

Comment: Use `JSON.parse(d)`.

Comment: You are using `angular.toJson` on a string. Do you not mean `angular.fromJson`?

Comment: angular.toJSON is similiar to JSON.stringify, hence d should be an object not a string -> var d = { 'nomAtribut': 'marca','tipus': 'String','mida': '15','prioritat': '1','obligatori': 'No'};      https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

angular.toJson Serializes input into a JSON-formatted string

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson

in your case you are serializing string ...

your code could look like this:

```
$scope.sendRow = function() {
    var d = {
        'nomAtribut': 'marca',
        'tipus': 'String',
        'mida': '15',
        'prioritat': '1',
        'obligatori': 'No'
    };

    $http.post("http://10.0.203.73/WS/ws.php/tipusactius/alta", angular.toJson(d)).success(function(data) {
        $scope.status = data;
})};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a `JSON` string to `JavaScript` object, you should use the `angular.fromJson()` [method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson).

Also, make sure to convert your single quotes `'` to double quotes `"` in your `JSON`:

```
// ' becomes " in your string
var d = '{"nomAtribut": "marca","tipus": "String","mida": "15","prioritat": "1","obligatori": "No"}';

$http.post("http://10.0.203.73/WS/ws.php/tipusactius/alta", angular.fromJson(d))
.success(function(data){
    $scope.status = data;
}
```

Comment: Why convert it to an object then back to a string again?

Comment: @MattLishman I tried your answer and it's not working I get the same error from the web service

Comment: @proktovief Can you see what is being sent in the network tab? Is it sending the correct data?

Comment: @MattLishman this is what is sending: "{\"nomAtribut\": \"marca\",\"tipus\": \"String\",\"mida\": \"15\",\"prioritat\": \"1\",\"obligatori\": \"No\"}"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JSON argument not locked by arbitrary reference.

Assigning a JSON string to a variable and passing it directly will work here.